# How to declare a struct variable with a linked list in it?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, linux-kernel

In my `.h` file, I have:

```
#include <linux/list.h>
struct myNode
{
    struct list_head list;
    int myID;
    int myBadge;
};
extern struct myNode firstNode;
```

For define *firstNode* variable in the `.c` file I have tried this:

```
#include "test.h"
INIT_LIST_HEAD(&firstNode.list);
```

but when I compile, I get the error:

```
expected declaration specifiers '...' before '&' token INIT_LIST_HEAD(&firstNode.list);
```

I'm not too familiar with what the error actually means (sorry, I'm not that familiar with C), so I'm not sure why/what this means.

Comment: We'll need you to give a bit more of your code to help.

Comment: Did you include the `list.h` header?

Comment: The problem appears to be that no definition of `INIT_LIST_HEAD` is in scope at the point where you attempt to use it.

Comment: Dunno why you were downvoted.  HOWEVER, do not use Linux kernel headers except for kernel code.  They are not intended for supporting userspace programs.

Comment: "sorry, I'm not that familiar with C", so why do you try such strange thing, Kernel linux is not a library you can't use it like it was an library.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, at *global scope* (that is, outside of any function's body) executable code is fobidden; only declarations and definitions may be used here.

For define `firstNode` global variable and *initialize* list in it use `LIST_HEAD_INIT` macro:

```
#include "test.h"
struct myNode firstNode =
{
    .list = LIST_HEAD_INIT(list);
}
```

Comment: Actually, a macro can play one of different roles. `LIST_HEAD` is a *definition* macro - using it one may defines a variable of list type. `LIST_HEAD_INIT` is an *initialization* macro - it can be used as a right hand of variable's initialization statement. One may treat INIT_LIST_HEAD as *functional* macro - it performs some actions and doesn't return a value. So it can be used only as an executable code.

Comment: Exactly. The header you refer to defines a *functional* macro: it performs some actions, and doesn't return a value. Construction `do { ... } while(0)` is a commonly used for define such type of macros in Linux kernel. Note that `LIST_HEAD_INIT` macro definition uses `{a, b}` construction, which can be assigned to a structure variable with fields of appropriate type.